# Is it possible to disable the clickable HeaderLayout in NavigationView?

Tags: android, navigationview

Been looking for ways to disable the default clickable header layout in `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```

Tried to do `clickable=false` in the `NavigationView` but it didn't work.

I also tried `setClickable(false)` programmatically didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it by inflating it in Java instead of XML.

```
navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.drawer_header);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `android:enabled="false"` if available for NavigationView.

Comment: Sadly it's not available or should I say I can't use it that way. Since the NavigationView mixes the header and the body all at once.

Answer (score 0):

the navigationView has a listview in it. reference the listview programatically. then add your own header and turn off selection on the header. to turn off selection of header use:

listview.addHeaderView(myheaderView,null,false);